# using Python to find 2 related strings that are on different lines

Tags: python

I wrote a program that outputs data in a large file after iterating through the many devices it collects information from.
The new information from new devices is appended onto this file, so it's basically a large file with similar (but not exactly) the same information every 10 lines or so.

What I need to do is FIND a specific string (in this case, I've worked in a special character used for identification purposes in each iteration of the data in the large file), then obtain the text that follows that particular identification character, 2 lines down. Brownie points if it allows me to check if this is the correct data I'm looking for (i.e., contains the word 'version').

For example, the text file could look like:

```
trying 1.1.1.1
connected to 1.1.1.1
username: xxxx
password: xxxx
>>2001
issue command y
y = version
```

The above text would be repeated around 100 times, with unique identifiers being listed after '>>'.  What I need to do in Python is open the file with the text, loop through it, find the '>>' and collect the version listed 2 lines below.  I then need to print them on the screen in a way that shows '>>2001  y = version' looping all the way through '>>2099 y = version'.

Comment: the text file above should say 

'
trying 1.1.1.1
connected to 1.1.1.1
username: xxxxx
password: xxxxx
>>2001
issue command y
y = version
'

Comment: please paste your code, an input example and desired output. Please refer to the posting guidelines, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Dalvenjia, note that instead of the URL (`stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`), you could type \[ask\], which will appear as [ask] in the comments. Same for \[mcve\] ([mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

A [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) would be a great tool for this. For example:

```
# you'll want to load this from an actual file instead; 
# I'm just including it as a literal for example
file_contents = '''trying 1.1.1.1
connected to 1.1.1.1
username: xxxx
password: xxxx
>>2001
issue command y
y = version'''


# Summary of this regex: find and capture your ">>2001" line,
# followed by a line that doesn't get captured, followed by a line that gets captured
matches = re.compile('\n(>>\d+)\n.*\n(.*)\n?').findall(file) 
# matches should now be [('>>2001', 'y = version')]

for match in matches:
    print(match[0], match[1])`
```

Welcome to the wonderful world of regular expressions!

You can experiment with this regex at [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97774)

Comment: thank you for both replies.  I will play around with it and let you know what works.  I really do appreciate it !

Comment: You're welcome. Upvotes and choosing a best answer are good ways to show thanks!

Comment: I will say that I played with the first suggestion and it does provide what I want, however it gets stuck in an infinite loop.  I've tried to put a counter in place to stop the loop, but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts thusfar.

Comment: to be quite honest, I would love to use the regex expression solution, but I dont know how to use them well enough to fix it should my file change in the future.

Comment: Fair enough! coding is often about choosing when it's time to learn the next thing rather than work with what you know :)
I fixed the regexpal link at the end - it's a sandbox where you can play around and learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a list and `loop` through the list looking for your identifier then print the desired items. For example:

**Code:**

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('>>'):
            print line, data[data.index(line)+2]
```

**Input file:**

```
trying 1.1.1.1
connected to 1.1.1.1
username: xxxx
password: xxxx
>>2001
issue command y
y = version
>>2002
issue command y
y = versionx
>>2003
issue command y
y = versionz
```

**Output:**

```
>>2001 y = version
>>2002 y = versionx
>>2003 y = versionz
```

Comment: You should `enumerate` to avoid the `list.index`.This will be really slow for large files.